# Quando o assunto é sobre opiniões, onde devo perguntar?

Tags: suporte

Surgiu-me a necessidade de pedir opiniões na montagem de um **framework**, no SoPT, pode fazer este tipo de pergunta?

Creio que iria ser fechada como *fora de escopo* porém não achei nada sobre, de como fazer uma pergunta.

Como devo proceder?

Comment: Vc pode fazer esses tipos de perguntas no chat e discutir sobre alguns outros assuntos com as pessoas que estão online

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida, minha reputação não me fornece este recurso no momento.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, é sobre Framework CSS, o de PHP eu já montei e tenho tudo que necessito, mas seria bom se o SOPT, tivesse uma forma de perguntar baseado em opiniões. Iria ajudar muito.

Comment: @Guilherme agora ela já fornece.

Comment: @Stormwind, como assim? Se eu fazer uma pergunta baseada em opiniões, com certeza será fechada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depende da pergunta, até o momento não entendi o que exatamente você quer pergunta, se você quer saber o que é um Framework, já tem resposta:  [Qual é a diferença de API, biblioteca e Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/3635) - Lendo as respostas notará que framework pode fazer várias coisas, não é só WEB. Pra resumir, framework é um conjunto de libs no qual você trabalha em um "ecossistema" dele para desenvolver uma aplicação especifica. Sendo sobre PHP dê uma olhada em frameworks existentes como [Silex](https://silex.symfony.com) ou [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com), estude eles e terá uma noção de como criar.

Se for um framework como Bootstrap, você pode olhar pra documentação do bootstrap e estudar e então tentar criar o seu proprio, outros frameworks mais simples você pode olhar para isto:

- https://getuikit.com (pessoalmente achei um excelente "framework")
- https://foundation.zurb.com

Se tiver uma duvida muito especifica sobre como implementar uma funcionalidade "especifica" (enfase na palavra "especifica"), então formule uma pergunta, caso contrário a probabilidade é que sua pergunta poderá cair no chamado *"ampla demais"* ou *"baseado em opiniões"*

**É importante** notar que o site não tem espaço para perguntas sobre opinião, no máximo o chat, mas só pra constar, no chat ninguém tem obrigação de responder e nem sempre alguém vai lhe dar atenção, geralmente o chat é um local mais descontraído e muitas vezes não falamos de tecnologia com propósito de resolver problemas e nem tentando ser construtivos.

---

### Opinião

Agora vou deixar uma opinião bem pessoal, pra que criar um framework do zero, a não ser que você vá criar algo muito inovador ou realmente leve e incrível ao mesmo tempo, criar algo assim para produção pode ser um baita tiro no pé, existem frameworks gratuitos para isto, para serem usados, criar por criar nem sempre será um bom caminho.

~ como eu disse é opinião pessoal

Comment: ps: eu criei meu próprio framework PHP porque ele tem um diferencial se comparado a outros do mercado, Front-end eu adotei o bootstrap mesmo, mas estou pensando em adotar o Uikit

Comment: Então, maioria dos meus desenvolvimentos eu uso Bootstrap como de costume, mas tem um porém, antes de mais nada quero dizer, que não quero reinventar a roda e sim fazer um padrão próprio meu. A sua opinião realmente confirma, mas a dúvida era se pra criar um framework css é necessário utiliazar sass ou less. acho que iria ficar ampla de mais a pergunta.

Comment: @Guilherme Sass ou Less é gosto pessoal, eu por exemplo não uso nenhum pré-compilador, eu trabalho com CSS puro sempre, porque me sinto mais confortável assim, Sass e Less não são regras e nem padrões WEB, ou seja não são obrigatórios. Acho que passará anos, chegará o CSS4 e eu ainda vou me recusar a usar pré-processadores xD - Resumindo use o que você se sente confortável.

Comment: Me sentia tão confortável usando **ie** na época do orkut, hoje em dia tá muito fressurento a internet mas fazer o que é a tecnologia rsrs obrigado pela resposta cara, att;

Comment: @Guilherme concordo em parte contigo, sim existe muita "frescuragem" realmente, ainda sim o IE é o culpado do próprio fracasso, foi a parceria de grupos da google, mozilla e apple que deram uma melhora nas tecnologias, coisa que o IE (e até a W3 tem um pouco de culpa) teve espaço pra fazer e não fez :/ - Até xará.